# Negation inside printf

Tags: c, mingw

I have the below code and I am not sure why negation inside printf is different from doing negation outside?

```
char d=0x04;
printf("Value of d= %X\n",~d);
d=~d;
printf("Value of d= %X\n",d);
```

The result printed is FFFFFFFB and FB.
That means can I say that, inside printf, expressions are converted to integer type (default promotion) and hence 4 bytes are appearing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the operation of the `~` operator is performed, the type of the operand it promoted to `int`. This means the result of: `~0x04` will be `0xFFFFFFFB` in your case, as the width of type `int` appears to be 32 bits.

If the value `0xFFFFFFFB` is passed to printf it isn't promoted to `int` as it is already of that type, and it is printed out.

If `0xFFFFFFFB` is assigned back to `d`, a conversion from `int` to `char` in an implementation-defined manner is done. In your case the resulting value is: `0xFB`. When `d` is passed to printf, it gets promoted to `int`, the value of `0xFB` when promoted to `int` stays the same, and it gets printed out.