# Negation operator on unsigned char

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, negation, integer-promotion

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned char a = 5;
    printf("%d\n",~a);
    printf("%d\n",a=~a);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the accepted answer here [Negation inside printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38741805/negation-inside-printf) , in the first printf, `a` should get promoted to an `int` and the output should be a large negative number. But the output of the first printf is -6. Can you please explain why the output is -6 and why the char is not promoted to int in this case?

Comment: Why do you expect a huge negative number? In the linked question, `FFFFFFFB` gets printed, which is `-5` in hex.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm talking about the question OP linked to, not this one.

Comment: `!` is logical negation.  `-` is arithmatic negation.   `~` is the bit wise complement.

Comment: "and the output should be a large negative number." --> not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can you please explain why the output is -6 and why the char is not promoted to int in this case?*

Not really, because it ***is*** being promoted to an `int` - and, as an `int`, inverting all the bits will (assuming [two's-complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and no overflow) convert a positive `n` value into the negative value, `-(n+1)`.

This modification to your code may demonstrate what's happening:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    printf("%d\n", ~a); // Prints -6
    printf("%d\n", a = (unsigned char)~a); // Prints 250 - lower 8 bits of the int
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is getting promoted and `~5 == -6` in two's complement. Assuming two's complement, the bitwise negation of a small positive number will yield a small negative number. The number will appear large only when viewed as an `unsigned`, which is what `"%X"` in the linked answer does.

(BTW, the number in the linked answer should also have been cast to `unsigned` before being printed as `"%X"`, because `printf` technically requires exact correspondence between the conversion specifier and the type of the passed argument).

Answer (score 1):

For two's complement internal representations if you have an integer value `x` then the expression

```
x + ~x + 1
```

is equal to 0.

So for this declaration

```
unsigned char a = 5;
```

the operand of the expression `~a` will be promoted to the type int.

So you will have that

```
~a + a + 1 = 0
```

that is

```
~a + 5 + 1 = 0
```

And as a result the value of the expression `~a`

```
~a = -5 -1 = -6
```

In binary notation it looks like (provided that the type int occupies 4 bytes)

```
a ( = 5 ) = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101
~a        = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010

a + ~a    = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

The last binary value is the representation of `-1` in the type int.

In this call

```
printf("%d\n",a=~a);
```

at first the expression ~a was truncated to an object of the type unsigned char dues to the assignment

```
a=~a
```

That is the expression will have a non-negative number.